Increase of value By ID and Date in two or more columns
I need to find if there is an increase in two or more columns based on HHID and Date.
I took my source file, duplicated it twice. In one I found the minimum date by sorted and using Table.Buffer to take out the duplicates and keep just the minimum date. I did the same for maximum. I appended the queries back together and now have the min and max date with the value, now I need to compare them to see which questions had an increase from the min date to max date.
I know that I went all wrong with this but its the only way I can figure out even where to start.
In the image I highlighted in green the ones that have an increase over the previous data and question, in red a decrease and in orange no change. I would expect count of the number of increases like;  2 or more green columns = true 1 or less = false
HHID    Date    Question    Points
1   3/21/2022   Attendance  3
1   3/21/2022   Childcare   3
1   3/21/2022   Education   2
1   3/21/2022   Employment  2
1   3/21/2022   Family Development/Parent Engagement    2
1   3/21/2022   Family Safety   3
1   3/21/2022   Financial Management    3
1   3/21/2022   Food Security   3
1   3/21/2022   Housing 5
1   3/21/2022   Income  3
1   3/21/2022   Language Skills 0
1   3/21/2022   Literacy Grades 1 - 3   3
1   3/21/2022   Physical and Mental Health  1
1   3/21/2022   Substance Use   2
1   3/21/2022   Transportation  5
1   6/13/2024   Attendance  4
1   6/13/2024   Childcare   2
1   6/13/2024   Education   1
1   6/13/2024   Employment  4
1   6/13/2024   Family Development/Parent Engagement    4
1   6/13/2024   Family Safety   4
1   6/13/2024   Financial Management    4
1   6/13/2024   Food Security   3
1   6/13/2024   Housing 3
1   6/13/2024   Income  3
1   6/13/2024   Language Skills 5
1   6/13/2024   Literacy Grades 1 - 3   5
1   6/13/2024   Physical and Mental Health  5
1   6/13/2024   Substance Use   4
1   6/13/2024   Transportation  4


what's the expected output? still not clear about your question. Could you pls elaborate more?

This is the exact question I am being asked.
'Number of families who have improved their score on the Self-Sufficiency Matrix in two or more columns.'
I know I need to group by HHID, find the earliest and latest date, get rid of the rest then compare each question and find if there are two or more questions with a higher score than the previous date.
I would want to count how many HHIDs have an increase for two or more questions.

what about first increase then decrease? from 1 to 3 to 2? and what about from 4 to 7 to 3? One is last higher than earliest. The other is last is lower than earliest.will we count that?

I am thinking an increase from the min date to max date. So I would need to keep the min and max date, get rid of all the other dates and compare the two, and see if at least two of the questions are greater for each household.

Please check if this is what you want
Sample data

then create a new table
Table2 =
VAR tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Table',
        "check",
            IF (
                'Table'[Date]
                    = CALCULATE (
                        MIN ( 'Table'[Date] ),
                        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[HHID], 'Table'[Question] ),
                        'Table'[Date]
                    )
                    || 'Table'[Date]
                        = CALCULATE (
                            MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
                            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[HHID], 'Table'[Question] ),
                            'Table'[Date]
                        ),
                1
            )
    )
VAR tbl2 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( tbl, [check] = 1 ),
        "HHID", 'Table'[HHID],
        "Date", 'Table'[Date],
        "Question", 'Table'[Question],
        "Points", 'Table'[Points]
    )
RETURN
    tbl2


